# MapView error on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was using MapView on Xcode, and everything was working fine, but when I added the following line

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

to ViewController.m, I get the error

> Assigning to 'id<MKMapViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const 
>       __strong'

Here is my code:

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self; //The line I added that creates the error
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView *mapview;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode? (It's just an IDE.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare that your class implements the MKMapViewDelegate methods. In your ViewController.h header file, change the line

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
```

to

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
```

Comment: I completely forgot that step ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare that you respond to `MKMapViewDelegate` calls.

To do this, simply update the header file for the corresponding class (`ViewController.h` in your example) as follows:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
```